# How to pass a variable from an alert dialog to another class that updates immediately

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog, background-color

So basically, I have a class that extends a `DialogFragment` which creates an `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice`. I want to pass a `String` containing a specific color to another class so that I can dynamically and immediately change the colors of the buttons when an option/choice is clicked but my code does not work

```js
public class ThemeDialog extends DialogFragment {


  public static String  blueColor, redColor,
  pinkColor, cyanColor, , greenColor,  yellowColor, 
  public static String selectedColor;
  public static String colorToPass;

  public static ThemeDialog newInstance() {
    ThemeDialog f = new ThemeDialog();
    return f;
  }

  int defaultSelectedPosition;

  ArrayList names = new ArrayList();


  @Override
  public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    dialog.setTitle("Please Select");
    dialog.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        //Action when cancel is clicked
        dialog.dismiss();
      }
    })

    selectedColor = "#2196F3";

    blue = "Material Blue";
    red = "Material Red";
    pink = "Material Pink";
    cyan = "Material Cyan";
    green = "Material Green";
    yellow = "Material Yellow";

    blueColor = "#2196F3";
    redColor = "#F44336";
    pinkColor = "#E91E63";
    cyanColor = "#00BCD4";
    greenColor = "#4CAF50";




    names.add(blue);
    names.add(red);
    names.add(pink);
    names.add(yellow);
    names.add(deepOrange);
    names.add(brown);
    names.add(teal);

    ArrayAdapter < String > adapter = new ArrayAdapter < String > (getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice, names);



    dialog.setSingleChoiceItems(adapter, defaultSelectedPosition, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        //Action when any item is clicked


        ListView lw = ((AlertDialog) dialog).getListView();
        Object checkedItem = lw.getAdapter().getItem(lw.getCheckedItemPosition());
        //Passes color hex in string 
        if (checkedItem.equals(blue)) {
          selectedColor = blueColor;
        }
        if (checkedItem.equals(red)) {
          selectedColor = redColor;
        }



      }
    });

    return dialog.create();
  }




}
```

```js
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  //Gets variable from ThemeDialog class
  public String color = ThemeDialog.selectedColor;

  // The Buttons I want colored
  public static int[] coloredItems = {
    R.id.plus,
    R.id.minus,
    R.id.multiply,
    R.id.divide,
    R.id.percent,
    R.id.clear,
    R.id.square,
    R.id.point,
    R.id.equals,
    R.id.zero,
    R.id.delete
  };

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    
    colorFromThemeDialog();

  }

  //Method to set the color
  public void setColor() {
    for (int id: coloredItems) {
     findViewById(id).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(color));
    }
  }
  
  @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

       
        int id = item.getItemId();

  
        if (id == R.id.theme_dialog) {
            FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            DialogFragment Dialog = ThemeDialog.newInstance();
            Dialog.show(manager, "tag");

        }


        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
  
  
}
```

Comment: use an interface

Comment: use BroadCastReceiver to do so.